# Alternative to span

Tags: html, css, compatibility

basically I have some nasty markup:

```
<td colspan="2">
  <strong class="ajax_cart_quantity">8</strong>
    items
  <strong class="ajax_cart_total">
    271,60 $
  <span class="price-2"> (210,66 €)</span>
  </strong>
</td>
```

I formatted the code so it is easier to read. Here:s my problem: I need to give `.price-2` some styling (smaller font).

What I can't do: use class or attributes, because total value is updated and refreshed via ajax, and giving class attribute to `span.price-2` breaks down json.

What I can do: wrap second price in some distinctive elements without classes and attributes.

There are already some seletors in core css which target second price `table span`. So basically I need to come up with some other inline element line `span`, so I can create my own styling selector for `price 2`.

I need something compatible with the older browsers too.
Thank You

Comment: What does AJAX and JSON have to do with breakage caused by adding a class? Instead of explaining why you can't do the obvious (add a class) this just confuses the situation even more.

Comment: How about an `<em>` or `<small>`? They're both valid.

Comment: It just does. I'd rather make a selector than go searching for the error (it's core error anyway,not mine).

Comment: I think `small` will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd use `<em>` or `<small>`. They're both valid and fully supported, furthermore they impart some style of their own which could be useful.

But you don't event need a replacement - just use span *without* the class and target it differently in the CSS:

```
.ajax_cart_total span {font-size:0.8em;}
```

Comment: Did you mean `.ajax_cart_total .price2 span`?

Answer (score 2):

Leave the html as it is add to CSS a specific selector:

```
table td strong span.price-2 {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
```

Add the `!important` only if the selector (`table td strong span.price-2`) is not specific enough.

This works even in ancient browsers.

Comment: The table span selector was meant to target other spans, while this span is a span within span. Also it applied more property (not just font-size). What's more, .price-2 elements is used in different places accross the page (the price used to be just text)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need another inline element that (still) works, you could make use of `<b>` or `<i>` - those work inline are still supported :)

(`<b>` was used for **bold** and `<i>` for *italics*, but in HTML these text effects are currenty accomplished with `<strong>` and `<em>`). `<b>` and `<i>` still exist albeit used much less frequently to achieve the aforementioned text emphasis. They will be interpreted inline.)

Comment: `<b>` wasn’t replaced by `<strong>` (same for `<i>`/`<em>`), their meaning changed: `<b>` is for bold text, while `<strong>` is for *important* text (which is displayed in bold). This is a purely semantic difference. Also, regarding other tags in older browsers, they’re interpreted as *inline* elements, not blocks. This is the default behavior when a browser encounters a tag it doesn’t know.